# Evaluating elevation change between multiple LiDAR datasets

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, interpolation, lidar, inverse-distance-weighted

I am hoping to get some insight from others who are familiar with comparing multiple LiDAR surveys to one another. I have two LiDAR surveys with similar extents that I would like compare for elevation change. I have the point cloud .las files for each of them, so I am able to manipulate the original data in any way that is necessary.

So far, I have created 3 ft. resolution (1/2 the sampling density) rasters for each of the surveys using the same (IDW) interpolation method. I was hoping that by creating a grid of the same size for each of the surveys that I would get rid of any artifacts in the subtraction product. This has not been the case thus far as there is grid-like striping in the subtraction product. These artifacts result in about a +/- 3 feet error in the product. Maybe with a 3 feet grid spacing this is the best that I can hope for??

Does anyone have a comparison method that works well for them?

Comment: Is it mandatory that the gridding happens to a finer resolution than the (ground) point spacing? Usually, to avoid artifacts, using 1 to 3 times the **average ground point spacing** is better. For example, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101970/lidar-las-to-bare-earth-dem-average-points-spacing-and-cell-size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few thoughts that hopefully will assist you:

First, the fine print... I don't have any experience converting LAS to DEM, but I do have a fair amount of elevation change detection with LAS-derived DEMs.

Specific to the striping that you mentioned... as a US President once said, "I feel your pain!". In my experience striping (sometimes seen in DEM-derived hillshades, even resembling a hounds-tooth fabric pattern) has ALWAYS been due to improper resampling somewhere along the data handling chronology.  With elevation data, NEVER use the *Nearest Neighbor* option (which is, unfortunately, often displayed as the default option - and thereby easily bypassed).  I have found that the *Bilinear Interpolation* option generates great output without any striping.  So I would recommend that you repeat every command and tool used in your process to get the LAS data to its current state and wherever there's a resampling technique option in the tool dialog (for example, it's right there in the [Project Raster](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/project-raster.htm) tool dialog) use *Bilinear*.  For those tools that don't display a resampling technique, click the *Environments...* button at the bottom and replace any *Nearest Neighbor* options with *Bilinear* in the *Raster Storage* section.  It only takes one *Nearest Neighbor* somewhere in your chronology for stripes to make their unwelcome appearance!

Other thoughts:

You mention that you have data sets from two different LIDAR projects.  You'll need to assure that the two resulting DEMs are a) in the same CRS, both horizontally and [vertically](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291911/specifying-geoid-in-arcgis-raster-project-tool) and b) exactly aligned to each other in the X-Y dimensions.  The latter commonly involves adjusting the DEMs to fit several ground control points (think road intersections) located across the study area.  There's lots of how-to articles on the internet if you are unfamiliar.  I would also recommend becoming familiar (query GIS Stackexchange) with the *snap raster* concept found in *Environment Settings > Processing Extent*.

Even after taking pains to assure that both DEMs are aligned, [I've still had to solve weird patterns following subtraction](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283010/lidar-dem-produces-odd-results-related-to-topographic-aspect).  Happy processing!

Comment: Stu, thanks for the great feedback regarding the matter. I was not aware of raster snapping, though the thought of a misalignment has always run through my mind. I think that I generally have to much faith in the consultant/agency acquiring/processing the raw data.